# Can't input new data for a function of the pls package in R

Tags: r

I have a `pls` model for a spectroscopic data set. The data set consist of 2150 wavelengths (predictors) and 32 minerals (response). The model have been trained with 81 samples.
I tried to use the `RMSEP` and `R2` functions (mvrVal in the manual) of the package with a new data set of 34 samples, but i got "'newdata' had 35 rows but variables found have 81 rows".
And here is the code i used.

```
m1<-plsr(minerales81[,1]~as.matrix(longitudes81),method="simpls",)
RMSEP(m1,newdata=as.matrix(longitudes2),ncomp=1:20,)
```